# Uniqueness of majoration proofs

Tags: coq

Is there an equivalent of the uniqueness of identity proofs, for types with a decidable order ? In particular, in the type of Peano natural numbers ? Is it implemented somewhere in Coq's library ? (I couldn't find it)

It seems true on the natural numbers, because a proof that `n <= p` looks the same as a proof of `n == p` : it iteratively destructs `n` and `p` until the number on the left reaches 0, then concludes.

Comment: How would that work for something like `Inductive lt_bool : bool -> bool -> Prop := | lt_false_true_1 : lt_bool false true | lt_false_true_2 : lt_bool false true.`  It seems like uniqueness of a proof of `lt_bool false true` then would imply full proof irrelevance.

Comment: @DanielSchepler Yes, `lt_false_true_1 = lt_false_true_2` looks hard to prove. I don't see how it would lead to full proof irrelevance though.

Comment: Basically, `forall (P : Prop) (pf1 pf2 : P)` you can define a map `lt_bool false true -> P` which provably maps `lt_false_true_1` to `pf1` and `lt_false_true_2` to `pf2`.  So, `lt_false_true_1 = lt_false_true_2` would imply `pf1 = pf2`.

Comment: For `<=` on the naturals, there is a trivial Agda proof of (the equivalent of) `forall n m (p q : n <= m), p = q`. It ought to be true in Coq as well, but I'm currently failing to wrestle Coq into accepting a proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mathcomp has a lemma like that, i.e.

```
Lemma le_irrelevance m n le_mn1 le_mn2 : le_mn1 = le_mn2 :> (m <= n)%coq_nat.
```

together with its proof in [ssrnat.v](https://github.com/math-comp/math-comp/blob/528d71783b0e34181d720a6456ea0a87a01abe25/mathcomp/ssreflect/ssrnat.v#L405). Notice the `coq_nat` scope, which means we are using the *inductive* definition of `<=`, as opposed to Mathcomp's boolean version mentioned by @ejgallego.

Answer (score 0):

The way I see it is that the type of the decidable operators should not land in `Prop` but in `bool`, as done in Math-Comp.

This way, if `<= : T -> T -> bool` you get irrelevance pretty easily.

Comment: I tried this in my original problem (which I didn't post here). I have proven a proposition for all integers below a certain number `n`, so `forall k:nat, k <= n -> P`. Then I want to define a function that `match le_dec k n | left L` and I get a proof `L : P` that I can feed to something else. If I switch to `forall k:nat, if k <=? n then P else True`, how do I get a proof of `P` inside `match k <=? n` ? It does not typecheck.

Comment: You want to use the corresponding reflection lemma for <=